# auth. Refresh token and access token flow?

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I am a little confused about the existence of refresh tokens.

I know that refresh tokens are used to renew the access token and have a shorter lifespan.

For instance, I wonder why refresh tokens are necessary and why compromising the access token doesn't necessarily mean the refresh token is also compromised.

Both tokens are attached to cookies after authentication for further authorization on protected routes.

If there is a possibility of access token vulnerability, why can't refresh tokens also have vulnerabilities since both are attached to cookies with HTTPS-only and other security measures?

I searched the  the internet, chatgpt, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The access token is short lived, eg 15 minutes, and sent by the client on API requests, eg to routes such as `/api`.

The refresh token is long lived, eg 4 hours. and sent to a different endpoint, such as `/refresh`. It is not sent during API requests, so is exposed less often. It can only be used if the attacker also has a credential such as a client secret.

Refresh tokens enable the API credential (access token) to be short lived, without needing to involve the user every time one expires. If the access token is stolen it cannot be misused by an attacker to access your data for long.

Whether tokens are referenced by cookies or sent directly, these OAuth semantics should be followed. Backend credentials should only be sent where they are needed, and each type of credential should be able to have its own lifetime.

Some technology stacks though, in particular for websites, may follow older `session ID` semantics. These sometimes do not separate access and refresh token concerns in the preferred ways. A stolen session ID cookie might therefore be used to access your data for a whole 4 hours.